# Pandas Python muito lento

Tags: python, pandas

Alguem pode me ajudar? estou fazendo a leitura de um arquivo, faço algumas alterações e em seguida salvo em outra pasta. mas isso leva 2 horas, o arquivo tem 15 milhoes de linhas, teria algum metódo diferente e mais eficaz?

```
# LER ARQUIVO NA PASTA STAGING
arq5 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Usuário\staging\arquivo5.txt',delimiter='\t',encoding='cp1252',engine='python')


# FAZ ALTERAÇÕES NO ARQUIVO 
columns = ['PERIODO', 'CRM', 'CAT', 'MERCADO', 'MERCADO_PX', 'CDGLABORATORIO', 'CDGPRODUTO', 'PX']
arq5.drop(columns, inplace=True, axis=1)

# SALVA O ARQUIVO 5 COMO CSV NA PASTA ALPHA
arq5.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Usuário\alpha\arquivo5.txt', index=False)
```

Comment: Realmente é um arquivo muito grande, não conheço outro modo de fazer isso. Seu hardware não está limitando o processamento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `pandas` carrega o arquivo inteiro pra memória, e isso pode ser lento, no caso de arquivos muito grandes.

Tente não carregar o arquivo inteiro. O código abaixo faz o mesmo que o seu, porém sem usar `pandas` e sem carregar o arquivo inteiro na memória - ele vai lendo o arquivo de origem linha a linha, em seguida modificando, e salvando direto no destino:

```
colunas_remover = ['PERIODO', 'CRM', 'CAT', 'MERCADO', 
    'MERCADO_PX', 'CDGLABORATORIO', 'CDGPRODUTO', 'PX']
nome_arquivo = r'C:\Users\Usuário\staging\arquivo5.txt'
destino = r'C:\Users\Usuário\alpha\arquivo5.txt'

# LER ARQUIVO JA GRAVANDO O RESULTADO EM OUTRA PASTA
with open(nome_arquivo, encoding='cp1252', newline='') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    with open(destino, 'w', encoding='cp1252', newline='') as fw:
        colunas_manter = [c for c in cf.fieldnames if c not in colunas_remover]
        cw = csv.DictWriter(fw, colunas_manter, delimiter='\t',
            extrasaction='ignore') # ignora o que nao esta em "manter"
        cw.writeheader()
        cw.writerows(cf)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! o script funcionou perfeitamente, o problema agora é que o nome da coluna não esta vindo e as linhas estão alternando com uma linha com registro e outra não.

Comment: @VitorTenório Coloquei na resposta o `writeheader()` que faltou para colocar o nome das colunas. Agora quanto à alternação, existem pequenos ajustes no tratamento das quebras de linha dependendo da versão do python - qual python está usando?

Comment: Outra coisa @VitorTenório, a título de curiosidade, ficou mais rápido? Quanto tempo está demorando para rodar tudo agora?

Comment: deu certo o nome da coluna, perfeito! estou usando a versão 3.6 do python. muito mais rapido, leva em torno de 5min.

Comment: Que ótimo, redução considerável hein @VitorTenório, quase duas ordens de magnitude. Adicionei o `newline=''` nos dois `open()`s  o que deve resolver o problema das linhas duplas para o python 3.6; qualquer coisa me fale!

Comment: certinho :).. uma duvida, preciso fazer um group by em uma coluna, se não for demais pode me mostrar como faço?

Comment: eu tinha pensando em fazer pelo pandas, mas isso levaria mais tempo de processamento e voltarimos ao fundo do poço kk

Comment: @VitorTenório se os dados estiverem ordenados, você pode usar o `itertools.groupby()`... Sugiro abrir nova pergunta com exemplo de entrada e de saída

Comment: Legal!! muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @VitorTenório Não se esqueça de colocar na nova pergunta um exemplo de como é o seu arquivo de origem, e um exemplo de como você gostaria que ficasse o arquivo de saída. Essas informações são essenciais para te ajudar com groupby